# UIToolBar lose translucent when clipsToBounds in iOS7.x

Tags: ios, ios7, uitoolbar

Usually i use UIToolBar to fake the live blur effect, it has been working great for me. But there is a place I need to have a **rounded corner toolbar**, however, whenever I set the cornerRadius and clipsToBounds, the translucent (blur) effect is gone, my tool bar becomes transparent.

here is my code:

```
UIToolbar *blurView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
blurView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
blurView.layer.cornerRadius = self.height / 2;
blurView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0];
```

here is a screen shot when **clipsToBounds = YES**, the corner is rounded, but the blur is gone.

[image]

But if i **comment clipsToBounds out**, the blur effect is back, but the corner is not rounded anymore.

[image]

The even stranger part is this issue **only happens in iOS7.x, everything works perfectly in iOS8.x** with the exactly same codes.

just in case if you wondering, here is how it looks on iOS8.x and how it should look on iOS7.x

[image]

I have been searching around on Stackoverflow and Google, can't find any clue. Please Help!

Comment: `blurView.layer.cornerRadius = self.height / 2 - 0.5;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `blurView.layer.cornerRadius = self.height / 2 - 0.5;`

Comment: that works... i can't believe that UIToolbar in iOS7 doesn't take a rounded number as it's corner Radius...